# Install MongoDb Driver in Netbeans

Tags: java, mongodb, netbeans

I have installed the MongoDb Plugin in NetBeans.

I found the quickstart guide here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/

When I try to use the imports NetBeans can not find them.
In Visual Studio I would just use the NuGet Package manager.
What do I have to do in NetBeans?

The dependencies XML where would that go?

Answer (score 0):

#### Have you included the external JARs in NetBeans?

Hover your mouse pointer over your desired project name, and <kbd>right-click</kbd>. Select `Properties > Libraries (found under Categories section) > Add JAR/Folder`.

From the file chooser, specify the location of the JARs you downloaded, and click on `Add`.

Close the Properties Dialog Box, and expand the `Libraries` node under your project. You should be able to see the imported JARs.

Also, if you're downloading the `mongodb-driver-3.x.x.jar` file, you also need to download the `bson-3.x.x.jar` and `mongodb-driver-core-3.x.x.jar` files, and import all three in NetBeans.

I had the same issue, and had to beat my head over it for a long time. Hope my experience can help you with your issue.

> PS: The version of MongoDB driver you're using is quite outdated, and the usage syntax might be deprecated in future versions.